# Race condition for USB devices with Multiple VMs

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine

I have 4 USB devices ( same model ) connected to a Windows 7 host.
On my windows 7, I have two VMs ( VMware - Ubuntu ). I can connect two to each VM manually but If I restart any of the USB Devices one of VMs will take control of all off them ( or most of them ) . Is there a way to tell my VM to always connect to the same resource if it's available  and tell the other VM to ignore a certain devices?

Basically I want VM 1) to always connect to A and B
and VM2 ) to always connect to C and D

They should never take control of each others resources.

Answer (score 0):

In Virtualbox you can create filter and on KVM you can specifically set which usb drive to use.

I am not so sure on VM ware

Comment: The devices are all named the same, What should be the primary identification token for USB devices ?

Comment: I think I found it thanks,http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1011600